# Cant enable CORS on the server side NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, post, server

I can't enable `CORS` on the server-side. My frontend and backend servers have different ports. Here is how server-side is implemented:

```js
http
  .createServer(function (req, res) {
    // .. Here you can create your data response in a JSON format
    // const { headers, method, url } = req;
    // let body = [];
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Request-Method', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
      res.writeHead(200);
      res.end();
      return;
    }

    // const responseBody = { headers, method, url, body: JSON.stringify(data) };

    response.write('{asd: 123}'); // Write out the default response
    res.end(); //end the response
  })
  .listen(port);
```

And I call the `fetch` function from the frontend-side like this one:

```js
fetch('http://localhost:3035', {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'same-origin', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
      cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
      credentials: 'include', // include, *same-origin, omit
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(line), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => console.log(data))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

But still getting errors:

`Security Error: Content at http://localhost:3030/ may not load data from http://localhost:3035/.`

`TypeError: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."`

Comment: @CherryDT - write that up as an answer

Comment: Your default response is not valid json. Also sending POST but only allowing GET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You explicitly *disallowed* CORS on the client side by setting `mode: 'same-origin'` instead of the default `mode: 'cors'`.

To quote the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode):

> `same-origin` — If a request is made to another origin with this mode set, the result is simply an error. You could use this to ensure that a request is always being made to your origin.

Since `http://localhost:3035/` *is* another origin than `http://localhost:3030/`, the result is, exactly as designed, "simply an error".

Set it to `mode: 'cors'` or remove `mode` entirely since `cors` is the default anyway.

---

On a side note, `Access-Control-Request-Method` is a *request* header in the preflight request, not a response header. You should remove it.

---

As mentioned in the comments: For a credentialed request to work, you cannot use an allowed origin of `*`. If you don't want to hardcode the expected origin at this point though, you can avoid this problem by always returning the origin that the current request comes from, using `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin)`.

Comment: ok, so thanks. but I changed the mode to the `cors` and set the origin but the new error occurred: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3035/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘http://localhost:3035/’).`

Comment: What do you mean when you say you "set the origin"? What response headers do you see returned from your API when you look at the network tab?

Comment: on the server-side: `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3035/');`. Because If I set `*` it throws another error: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ‘http://localhost:3035/’. (Reason: Credential is not supported if the CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is ‘*’).`

Comment: unfortunately not, here are the headers that I seted up: ` res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, POST');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');`

Comment: If you see that error it means that you are making a credentialed request. This means either your request has a session cookie or has an Authentication header or has an Authorization header. Just sending back Access-Control-Allow-Credentials to true is **not enough**. One thing you need to know about credentialed requests is that browsers ban the origin `*` for such requests and disallows origin lists (sending more than one url as `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. The **only** thing that will work is to do `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3030')` -- note NOT 3035

Comment: there are have to be starts instead of empty singlequotes

Comment: .. for the general case you should do `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin)` - @CherryDT can you include this info in your answer?

Comment: another one error: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3035/. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).`

Comment: Oh. Forgot to mention. If you **really** want to use CORS for it's intended use - to ban other websites from using your API - you can check `req.headers.origin` and see if it matches your list of allowed websites: `if (req.headers.origin.match(SOME_RULE) {res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin)}`

Comment: @ЯрославТерещук - just do `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin)`

Comment: and set default response as valid JSON

Comment: I'm sorry, I misspelled the last but one instruction. It was, `response.write(JSON.stringify({ asd: 123 }));` instead of `res.write(JSON.stringify({ asd: 123 }));`. Thanks a lot, I appreciate your help.